# How to estimate mean using purrr

Tags: r, tapply, purrr

I was wondering why cant map function in purrr can't solve this query

`tapply(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl, mean)`

`# 4        6        8`

`#26.66364 19.74286 15.10000`

with

`mtcars %>% split(.$cyl) %>% map(~mean(mpg))`

`#$4
[1] NA`

`#$6
[1] NA`

`#$8
[1] NA`

`#Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(mpg) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(mpg) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default(mpg) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`

Comment: Whilst I like `purrr`, you could do this relatively easily with a group by statement, e.g. using `dplyr`:

    `library(dplyr)

    mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    summarise(mean_mpg = mean(mpg))`

Sorry, not sure if you were asking _why_ `purrr` can't do it, or just trying to find a way to do it not using `tapply()`

Answer (score 1):

We need to extract the specific column

```
library(purrr)
mtcars %>%
    split(.$cyl)  %>%
    map(~mean(.$mpg))
```

If we need to get a `vector`

```
mtcars %>% 
      split(.$cyl)  %>%
      map_dbl(~mean(.$mpg))
#     4        6        8 
#26.66364 19.74286 15.10000
```